# Angular Integration Testing - jasmine Spy - Can't mock a service method returning Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine, angular-test

I am new to doing integration testing. And the whole thing is so confusing.

For my first test, Seems like my spying is not returning the data as i intend to return it. Gives and error: Expected 0 to be 3. Will be great if someone could  help me understand what am I doing wrong.

Here is my service,page,spec file along with template:

**MyService**

```
    import { Data } from './../data/data.model';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class MyService {
      private _data = new BehaviorSubject<Data[]>([]);

      get data() {
        return this._data;
      }

      constructor() {}

      getAllData() {
        return of([
          {
            id: '1',
            title: 'Rice',
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Wheat',
          },
          {
            id: '33',
            title: 'Water',
          },
        ]).pipe(
          tap((data) => {
            this._data.next(data);
          })
        );
      }
    }
```

**DataPage Component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { MyService } from '../services/my.service';
    import { Data } from './data.model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-data',
      templateUrl: './data.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./data.page.scss'],
    })
    export class DataPage implements OnInit {
      allData: Data[];
      dataServiceSub: Subscription;
      isLoading: boolean;

      constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dataServiceSub = this.myService.data.subscribe(
          (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.allData = data;
          }
        );
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.dataServiceSub) {
          console.log('ngOnDestroy');
          this.dataServiceSub.unsubscribe();
        }
      }

      ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.myService.getAllData().subscribe(() => {
          console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
```

**DataPage.spec**

```
    import { MyService } from '../services/my.service';
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

    import { DataPage } from './data.page';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';

    describe('DataPage', () => {
      let component: DataPage;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<DataPage>;
      let serviceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MyService>;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [DataPage],
          providers: [
            {
              provide: MyService,
              useClass: MyService
            },
          ],
          imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataPage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      }));

      fit('Should show list of data if data is available', () => {
        serviceSpy = TestBed.get(MyService);
        spyOn(serviceSpy, 'getAllData').and.returnValue(of([
          {
            id: '1',
            title: 'Rice',
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Wheat',
          },
          {
            id: '33',
            title: 'Water',
          },
        ]));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const element = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
          '[test-tag="dataList"] ion-item'
        );
        console.log(
          fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[test-tag="dataList"]')
        );
        expect(element.length).toBe(3);
      });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <ion-content>
      <div test-tag="empty" class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-text color="danger">
          <h1>No data</h1>
        </ion-text>
      </div>
      <div test-tag="dataList">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let data of allData">
            <ion-label test-tag="title">{{data.title}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you put `console.log(component.allData.length)` in `spec` file . I think  it'll come as `3`. Please confirm before once

Comment: What's the difference of both approaches? Am I supposed to test component? I thought as part of integration testing I should be directly checking the template?

Comment: Btw, It's coming as zero.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here is the problem:

*You need to call `ionViewWillEnter()` to set the value of `this.allData`*'

Reason: Because you are having empty value while creating `BehaviorSubject`. And to emit value using `data` (**`this._data.next(data)`**) , you need to call `getAllData()`.

```
 import { MyService } from '../services/my.service';
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

    import { DataPage } from './data.page';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';

    describe('DataPage', () => {
      let component: DataPage;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<DataPage>;
      let serviceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MyService>;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [DataPage],
          providers: [ MyService ],
          imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataPage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      }));

      fit('Should show list of data if data is available', () => {
        component.ionViewWillEnter(); // or create an event which will trigger ionViewWillEnter()
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const element = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
          '[test-tag="dataList"] ion-item'
        );
        console.log(
          fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[test-tag="dataList"]')
        );
        expect(element.length).toBe(3);
      });
    });
```

Please note that there are few changes that I have done:

1. Removed `UseClass` (because you were not using it as it should)
2. Removed `spy` (because you already have a hardcoded value in the original service)

For your better understanding of testing in angular, you can refer [my article](https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49) which has also shown the use of `useClass` for your reference.

---

On a side note: Try to use `asObservable()`, and also follow the convention of using `$` when creating an `Observable` (`this.data$.asObservable()`). That is not a compulsion but accepted practice in the JS community.

```
get data() {
  return this._data.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: This works. I was under the assumption we shouldn't be calling the lifecycle hooks ourselves and detectchanges will be making the framework do it. Doesn't this beats the purpose of testing?

Comment: @RBz: Gald to hear that. Can you please mark it as an answer so that it can help others as well.  :)

Comment: Done! Could you share your thoughts on manually calling a lifecycle hook in test? Is it a good practice?

Comment: @RBz: It can be done depending on the testing scenarios. But i would like to highlight that `fixture.detectChanges` is different than calling `ngOnInit`.  Also, in the provided example, I have not called lifecycle hook. The `detectChanges` was called to let the angular know that a certain value has changed and it should accordingly refresh the template. This helped you to `const element` in the `it`  block

Answer (score 1):

To avoid pain with observables, I would recommend to use a mocking library like `ng-mocks`, and to check its article "How to mock observable streams in Angular tests" https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/extra/mock-observables.

In your case the test might look like that:

```js
describe('DataPage', () => {
  // mocks everything except DataPage
  beforeEach(() => {
    return MockBuilder(DataPage)
      .mock(IonicModule.forRoot())
      .mock(MyService);
  });

  // We need to stub it because of subscription in ionViewWillEnter.
  // in a mock service, ionViewWillEnter does not return anything.
  // But we need to tell it to return an empty observable stream
  // to avoid errors like cannot call .subscribe on undefined.
  // This line can be removed along with the debugging from the
  // component.
  beforeEach(() => MockInstance(MyService, 'getAllData', () => EMPTY));

  it('Should show list of data if data is available', () => {
    // spies the getter of the property the component uses.
    MockInstance(MyService, 'data', jasmine.createSpy(), 'get')
      .and.returnValue(of([
        {
          id: '1',
          title: 'Rice',
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          title: 'Wheat',
        },
        {
          id: '33',
          title: 'Water',
        },
      ]));

    // render (already with detected changes)
    const fixture = MockRender(DataPage);

    // assertions
    const element = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      '[test-tag="dataList"] ion-item'
    );
    console.log(
      fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[test-tag="dataList"]')
    );
    expect(element.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```